# How do I assign the delete key to another character in Linux with termios?

Tags: linux, system, termios

I've working on this problem where I need to assign a character to a become the delete key in Linux with termios. I've looked up resources and it seems like everyone is doing it this way but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

So I am trying to bind the 'q' character to become the new delete key. This is what I have. I am assigning the 'q' character be the new backspace but when I compile and run 'q' doesn't delete anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
int main()
{
struct termios err;
err.c_cc[VERASE] = 'q';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assigning a value to a struct won't do anything. Maybe look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/729585/remap-keys-without-xmodmap-or-any-x-tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*cough*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)

```
 ...
  struct termios err;
  tcgetattr(0, &err);
  err.c_cc[VERASE] = 'q';
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &err);
 ...
```